# Detecting DTO and Entities missing or misconfigured properties

Tags: c#, unit-testing, automapper

We have a pretty common scenario where we use Automapper to map DTOs and Entities. As you would expect a lot of properties are 1=1 in both classes with some exceptions here and there.

As number of classes and properties has grown, sometimes developers forget to keep properties in sync when renaming or removing them.

Can you suggest how we could reliably detect "unmapped" properties, preferably automatically?

Comment: when do you hope this automatic detection to happen? By a tool invoking?

Comment: We were considering to write unit tests, also do it for each pair doesn't look feasible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For such a problem I would recommend to use the `GetUnmappedPropertyNames` method of `IMapper` itself. Code and Test should explain the idea below:

The condition 
    (z.PropertyType.IsValueType || z.PropertyType.IsArray || z.PropertyType == typeof(string))

will detect unmapped properties from Value Types like int, enum, Guid, DateTime, all Nullable value types bool?, Decimal?, Guid?, and string.

And such filter let your test to ignore mapping for Entity Navigation properties kind of:

```
public virtual Class NavigationProperty {get;set} 
public virtual IList<Class> CollectionNavigationProperty { get; set; }
```

Code and test:

```
[Test]
public void Mapping_Profile_Must_Not_Have_Unmapped_Properties()
{
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.AddProfile<TestProfile>();
    });
    var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

    var unmappedProperties = GetUnmappedSimpleProperties(mapper);
    Assert.AreEqual(unmappedProperties.Count, 0);
}

private List<UnmappedProperty> GetUnmappedSimpleProperties(IMapper mapper)
{
    return mapper.ConfigurationProvider.GetAllTypeMaps()
        .SelectMany(m => m.GetUnmappedPropertyNames()
        .Where(x =>
        {
            var z = m.DestinationType.GetProperty(x);
            return z != null && (z.PropertyType.IsValueType || z.PropertyType.IsArray || z.PropertyType == typeof(string));
        })

        .Select(n => new UnmappedProperty
        {
            DestinationTypeName = m.DestinationType.Name,
            PropertyName = n,
            SourceTypeName = m.SourceType.Name
        })).ToList();
}

internal class UnmappedProperty
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public string DestinationTypeName { get; set; }
    public string SourceTypeName { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{this.PropertyName}: {this.SourceTypeName}->{this.DestinationTypeName}";
    }
}
```

Proving test at your service:

```
  [Test]
    public void Test_Mapping_Profile_Must_Detect_Unmapped_Properties()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
                cfg.AddProfile<TestMappingProfile>();
        });
        ar mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        var unmappedProperties = GetUnmappedSimpleProperties();
        Assert.AreEqual(unmappedProperties.Count, 12);
    }

    public class TestMappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public TestMappingProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<Source, DestinationValid>();
            CreateMap<Source, DestinationInvalid>();
        }
    } 


    internal class Source
    {
        public string Test1 { get; set; }
        public int Test2 { get; set; }
        public int? Test3 { get; set; }
        public decimal Test4 { get; set; }
        public string[] Test5 { get; set; }

        public Guid Test6 { get; set; }
        public Guid? Test7 { get; set; }
        public TransactionRealm Test8 { get; set; }

        public bool? Test9 { get; set; }
        public bool Test10 { get; set; }

        public DateTime Test11 { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Test12 { get; set; }
    }

    internal class DestinationValid
    {
        public string Test1 { get; set; }
        public int Test2 { get; set; }
        public int? Test3 { get; set; }
        public decimal Test4 { get; set; }
        public string[] Test5 { get; set; }

        public Guid Test6 { get; set; }
        public Guid? Test7 { get; set; }
        public TransactionRealm Test8 { get; set; }

        public bool? Test9 { get; set; }
        public bool Test10 { get; set; }

        public DateTime Test11 { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Test12 { get; set; }
    }

    internal class DestinationInvalid
    {
        public string Test1X { get; set; }
        public int Test2X { get; set; }
        public int? Test3X { get; set; }
        public decimal Test4X { get; set; }
        public string[] Test5X { get; set; }
        public Guid Test6X { get; set; }
        public Guid? Test7X { get; set; }
        public TransactionRealm Test8X { get; set; }
        public bool? Test9X { get; set; }
        public bool Test10X { get; set; }

        public DateTime Test11X { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Test12X { get; set; }
    }
```

where TransactionRealm  is an example of enum:

```
public enum TransactionRealm
{
    Undefined = 0,
    Transaction = 1,
    Fee = 2,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also alternative approach with `MapperConfiguration.AssertConfigurationIsValid()` method, which can be using either in unit tests and in run time. `AssertConfigurationIsValid()` method throws exception with detailed description of all detected unmapped properties. In business logic i'd recommend (for better performance) to initialize mapper in service static constructor with custom `MapperFactory` helper:

```
public class MyBLL
{
    private static IMapper _mapper;
    static MyBLL()
    {
        _mapper = MapperFactory.CreateMapper<DtoToEntityDefaultProfile>();
    }
}

public static class MapperFactory
{
    public static IMapper CreateMapper<T>() where T : Profile, new()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile<T>();
        });

        /// AssertConfigurationIsValid will detect 
        /// all unmapped properties including f.e Navigation properties, Nested DTO classes etc.
        config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

        config.CompileMappings();
        return config.CreateMapper();
    }

}
```